# Spring Boot - Save only ID when REST POST request, but get object when GET request

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I am building restful web app with spring boot. I have entity called "Currency" and I have another entity called "Event", they look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
public class Currency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    String title;

    public Currency() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

And Event entity (some columns are omitted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(table = "currency", name = "id")
    private Currency currency;

    public Event() {}

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

I already have currencies (USD, Euros so on) in Currency table and I don't want any other data in this table, I want to have only id of currency in Event table, not the whole object, so how I can manage to have Currency object(with currency name and id) while GET-ing event, but insert only id when POST-ing a new event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, unless only one event can ever be associated to a given currency, your mapping is wrong: the association between Event and Currency should be a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne: many events share the same currency.

Now to your question. When saving an event, you'll receive, from the browser, some JSON object containing the event information, including the ID of the currency to which the event refers. So all you need to do is to get the Currency instance that is identified by this id, and then create and persist an Event instance containing that currency:

```
Currency currnecy = em.find(Currency.class, currencyId);
// or, if you don't even want to hit the database:
// Currency currnecy = em.getReference(Currency.class, currencyId);

Event event = new Event();
event.setCurrency(currency);
em.persist(event);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I got the idea of your answer, but where should I have that code, I mean in controller or in service or in entity?

Comment: That's up to you. Access to the EntityManager should be in DAO/Repository components. I tend to directly access repositories from controllers unless the logic is complex and/or shared by many controllers; and in that case, I use a service. But that's not what matters here. What the code is not what matters. What matters is the **principle** of the solution: from the ID of an existing entity, you get a reference to the entity itself using JPA, and store that reference i the new entity.

Comment: The main problem was that it was ManyToOne relationship, not a OneToOne, as you said. Also in @JoinColumn a name needed to be the unique column name in Event entity not id (as conflict was happening). Thank You.